# List items being cutted by container with fixed height

Tags: html, css

I have hours trying to figure out how to avoid this bullet points at the bottom being cutted when the text is too long, the container of the unordered list has a max height of 200px and the list has 3 columns. The list overflows the container, but my question is that if it's possible to automatically arrange only the list items that fit that 200px container and maybe hide the rest, avoiding cutting the text?

Here's a little demo: https://jsfiddle.net/djyu7s2w/12/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">
      <p>I'm a list item</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.list {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: '4rem';
  margin: 0;
}

.list-item {
  text-align: 'left';
  margin: 0 0 32px 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what else you are expecting when using a `max-height` with `overflow: hidden;` on the container. The best you can do with this setup is specify a `media query` to change the font size so that it fits.

Comment: Have I understood correctly - starting with the first in the list and then moving to the second and so on, you want as many items as can fit in that container to show, and the rest to be never visible.

Comment: @AHaworth correct

Comment: I suspect you need JavaScript for this.

Comment: Is using a bit of JavaScript acceptable?

Comment: @AHaworth yup, I guess I'll try to do it with JavaScript, was trying to stick with pure CSS

Comment: Just an observation: you have the 4rem gap in quotes so it is not implemented (you need it to stop the bullet points landing in the previous column). And a question: does the width of the whole equal 100vw?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want to do is possible.

You could do one of the following:

- Set a `min-height: 200px` on the wrapper so the wrapper grows if the `<ul>` exceeds 200px
- Set  `overflow: scroll;` on the wrapper so the wrapper has a scroll bar.
- Set text-overflow styles on the `<li>`s so that text is limited to one or 2 lines

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make this work is to set media-query(s) when the text overflows outside of the `max-width: 200px;` I found that your text goes outside of the container at `512px` so I set a media-query instructing the text to go to `x-small` at the screen width. However, this makes the text barely legible.

I also removed the default margin on `p` and the margin you set on `li`.

What I would do is either change `overflow: hidden;` to `scroll;` so that you can still view the text in the container or use `min-height: 200px;` on the container so that the container resizes accordingly.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* overflow-y: scroll; */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.list {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: '4rem';
  margin: 0;
}

.list-item {
  text-align: 'left';
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 512px) {
  html {
    font-size: x-small;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list-item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <p>Sed aliquam, magna placerat semper</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <p>Aliquam ullamcorper sagittis</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <p>Nam ac fringilla nunc, a congue quam</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <p>Quisque maximus pharetra est, ac tristique nisl mollis egestas</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <p>Proin pulvinar dui</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <p>Duis vel sollicitudin</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```